# Não estou conseguindo enviar um parâmetro pra um método GET de uma API usando o cURL do PHP

Tags: php, api, libcurl, get, postman

Olá, estou tentando usar o cURL pra consumir uma API onde tem um método que recebe uma string como parâmetro. Esse método na API esta configurado como GET, então ele vai receber esse parâmetro validar ele dentro da função e me retornar outras informações que preciso.

Deem uma olhada no código:

```
public function ValidateStudents() {

    $url = "http://apialuno.apis.com/equipes/ValidarAlunos";

    $ch = curl_init();

    $ras = array(
        'ra' => '2013124007,1645948456,2016292895,2017193789'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $ras); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

O parâmetro que comentei é esse ras que está em um array. Ele retorna vazio.
No postman eu consegui utilizar normalmente, chamei a API e no body coloquei assim:

```
{
"ra":"2013124007,1645948456,2016292895,2017193789"
}
```

E quando envio pelo postman ele me retorna esse json:

```
[
{
    "ra": 2013124007,
    "nome": "WENDER LUI CAMPOS DA SILVA"
},
{
    "ra": 1645948456,
    "nome": "Não encontrado"
},
{
    "ra": 2016292895,
    "nome": "Aluno já pertence a outra equipe"
},
{
    "ra": 2017193789,
    "nome": "Aluno já pertence a outra equipe"
}
]
```

Preciso ter esse mesmo retorno que tive no postman na variável do php pra poder trabalhar com os dados posteriormente. Se alguém souber como faço pra resolver isso ficarei muito grato!

Comment: Você quer saber como consumir esta api dentro do curl, pelo que sei é só isso: `$variavel_que_recebe = json_decode($result);` vc pode usar `file_get_contents()` : veja aqui na [documentacão](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php). também , não precisa ser `curl`.

Comment: Passa assim os ras ['ra' => ['2013124007,1645948456,2016292895,2017193789']]

Comment: Não consegui ainda, n estou conseguindo enviar o body que são os ras por parâmetro. Pelo file_get_contents tbm não deu certo.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, tais fazendo uma busca usando o método POST enviando os parâmetros como body e com isso tens o retorno do JSON. O teu JSON tens que enviar como body ao consumir os dados do endereço. Esse endereço deve ajudar https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/563902-enviar-json-no-body-com-curl/

Comment: Como consigo passar o JSON no body, consegue escrever um código de exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que sua requisição não é um JSON válido. Você está tentando usar JSON, como setado em:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Então, deveria usar o `json_encode` quando envia a requisição, já que não fez isto anteriormente:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     json_encode($ras));
```

---

Enfim, isto funcionaria:

```
public function ValidateStudents() {

    $url = "http://apialuno.apis.com/equipes/ValidarAlunos";

    $ch = curl_init();

    $ras = array(
        'ra' => '2013124007,1645948456,2016292895,2017193789'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     json_encode($ras)); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```